# Cast operator in C : () or (int)?

Tags: c

I'm reading The C Programming Language II and in the operator precedence table they show the cast operator as `(type)`, so it make me bothered.

> Is the cast operator just `()` like a function operator or it includes the types as a whole like `(int)`, `(float)` ...?
>
> And if so, does it mean that I can declare a new operator by myself with `typedef`?

Answer (score 4):

Type-casting is done through `(type)`, where `type` is either a native type like `int` or `char *`, *or* a type-alias created through `typedef`.

Function-calling is done through the `()` operator.

They might look similar, but are very different, and are of course placed at different places. For example `(type) expression` is a type-cast, while `expression()` is a function call. You can of course combine the cast and the call operators like `(type) expression()` which means that you call a function and then cast the *returned value* of the function.

If you're wondering about the last, the mixed casting and call expression, it's because function calling have higher [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than casting, so the call will happen first.

Comment: So "()" is a cast operator,right?

Comment: @Best_Name No, `()` is the function call expression, `(type)` is a cast. Just writing `() expression` is not valid, it will give you a compiler error.

Comment: so (int),(float),(sometypeidefined) are operators right?

Comment: @Best_Name If placed in front of another expression, those are all type-cast operators.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: To add to the first line: also  `(struct foos)`, `(union foou)`

Answer (score 1):

C is a bit confusing here, as there are several operators that use the same syntax but have different meaning depending on context. To make things even worse, the same syntax could be used for things that aren't even operators. This is particularly true for `()`, which is used all over the C language.

`()` could mean one of the following:

- A parenthesized expression. This is a so-called primary expression, which is the fancy word for basic stuff that make precedence over all operators.
- The cast operator. There is only one cast operator for all types. You cannot re-define the meaning of operators in C (but you can in C++, through operator overloading).
- The function call operator.
- Part of a compound literal declaration.
- Or it could be part of a statement, a function declaration, function-like macro declaration/call, part of certain variable declarations etc etc. It is simply part of the core language syntax and appears here and there.

Comment: "There is only one cast operator for all types." sounds like there is one universal cast operator.  `(int)` `(double)` `(foo_T)` look like 3 different operators to me.  Perhaps re-word to express your intent more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

This is used for calling the function and declaring function for type casting also.
Function example:

```
public void show(){
  printf("this is function");
}
```

... in type casting

```
float a= 1.22;
in b = (int)a;
```

Answer (score 0):

() is only valid in combination with a function name before it, is is a function call expression (an empty one, meaning you call the function with no parameters)

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int bar = foo(); // foo is called with no parameters
printf("bar:%d",bar);
return 0;
}

int foo(void) {
return 3;
}
```

Casting however is done by using a Type expression inside brackets (either a native type or one defined via `typedef`), like for instance in this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int foo = (int) 19.21;
printf("foo = %d", foo); // Will print 19 because 19.21 (double literal) was cast to int
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Disagree with "() is only valid in combination with a function name before it, is is a function call expression (an empty one, meaning you call the function with no parameters)"  Other uses: `inf foo2();` declares a function with no information about its parameters.  `()` also used in casting to function pointers. `(int (*)())`. Also variable declarations `int *z()`, where z is not a function, but a [function pointer](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*z%28%29).